Как убрать кнопку подтверждения при активации бота в tdesktop?
Я хочу активировать deeplink: t.me/bot_name?start=XXX
Но в Desktop версии требуется подтвердить активацию кнопкой Start:

В мобильных версиях Telegram ссылка активируется автоматически без подтверждения.
Я бы хотел сделать форк официального репозитория, но не совсем понимаю, где именно мне нужно сделать изменения, чтобы отключить подтверждение.

вроде тг написан на qt/c++, попробуй скопировать через vscode репозиторий и через поиск найти start или что-то такое, ну или поищи уишки в файлах, оттуда сможешь найти название класса который используется для кнопки и от него уже ссылки в места где он используется. Как вариант еще через аишку спросить, codeium например

Тег [tag:с++] вообще к месту?
